# How do I use grep to find all the zip files in a directory?

Tags: grep

I have a directory with over 1000 files, and a few of them are .zip files, and I want to turn them all into .tgz files.

I want to use grep to make a list of file names. I have tried "grep *.zip" to no avail. Reading the man pages, I thought that * was a universal selector. Why is this not working?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `ls`, not `grep`.

Comment: Actually, since `*.zip` is expanded by the shell, you don't even need to use ls - you could use `echo *.zip`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should really use `find` instead.

```
find <dir> -iname \*.zip
```

Example: to search for all `.zip` files in current directory and all sub-directories try this:

`find . -iname \*.zip`

This will list all files ending with `.zip` regardless of case. If you only want the ones with lower-case change `-iname` to `-name`

The command `grep` searches for strings in files, not for files. You can use it with `find` to list all your `.zip` files like this

```
find . |grep -e "\.zip$"
```

Comment: Added some info on how to use `find` with `grep` if you're interested.

Comment: Given that .zip files might be coming from one of "those other platforms," it's conceivable that they'd potentially contain spaces.  Assuming the conversion process is bundled into a script like, say, `zip2tgz`, it might be slightly more convenient to either use `find -iname '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0 zip2tgz` or `find -iname '*.zip' -exec zip2tgz '{}' \;`

Answer (score 2):

Grep uses regular expressions by default. The expression you'd want is:

grep .zip$

You probably want to use `find` though.

find . -name '*.zip'

Or you can pipe find into grep

```
find . | grep .zip$
```

Comment: No need to pipe the results of find to grep, see above.